# javascript variable access error

Tags: javascript

I have the code snippet below:

```
var ret_ = function(x){
    return x;
}
var make_cps=function(x,c_){
    return c_(x);
}
var pred = {
    _position: 0,
    setPosition: function (i) {
        _position = i
    },
    getPosition: function () {
        return _position
    },
    _size: 0,
    setSize: function (i) {
        _size = i
    },
    getSize: function () {
        return _size
    },
    _context: null,
    setContext: function (x) {
        _context = x
    },
    run: function () {
        return function (c_) {
            return make_cps(_position, c_);
        }(ret_) == 2;
    }
}
```

When I run it like below, it runs correctly:

```
pred.setPosition(2)  
pred.setSize(10)  
pred.setContext(null)  
var res = pred.run()  
console.log(res)  // Output: true
```

but if I replace the `_position` to `getPosition()` an error occurs as `getPosition()` is not defined. Also if I change to `this.getPosition()` it says `this` doesn't have a member called `getPosition()`

```
var pred = {
    _position: 0,
    setPosition: function (i) {
        _position = i
    },
    getPosition: function () {
        return _position
    },
    _size: 0,
    setSize: function (i) {
        _size = i
    },
    getSize: function () {
        return _size
    },
    _context: null,
    setContext: function (x) {
        _context = x
    },
    run: function () {
        return function (c_) {
            return make_cps(this.getPosition(), c_); // gives Error here
        }(ret_) == 2;
    }
}
```

Please someone throw light on this issue.

Comment: Could it be that it's a `c_` that's not defined in this context?

Comment: @YePhIcK c_ is defined, it is provided by the ret_ argument to the function. I will add ret_ and make_cps also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've lost your context. Where you've put this.getPosition(), this will return as the window object.

If you alter the line to read

```
return make_cps(pred.getPosition(), c_);
```

It will work successfully.

Alternately, you can change the run function to read

```
run: function () {
  var that = this;

  return function (c_) {
      return make_cps(that.getPosition(), c_);
  }(ret_) == 2;
}
```

**Edit**: Clarification

The reason that _position is still working rather than suffering from the same issue is that you're not actually setting prev._position at all in your current code.

```
setPosition: function (i) {
    _position = i
},
getPosition: function () {
    return _position
}
```

What it's actually doing there is creating a new global variable called _position and using that instead.

This code should actually read:

```
setPosition: function (i) {
    this._position = i
},
getPosition: function () {
    return this._position
},
```

Comment: in my real application i have the `pred` object as an anonymous object, so i cant use `pred` in place of `this`. Also my real question is why `_position` can work but `getPosition()` cannot.

Comment: @weima In which case, use the alternative version (at the bottom).

The reason _position works but getPosition doesn't is that you're currently using _position incorrectly in your code.

You're currently setting and getting _position rather than the position variable in prev, making a new global called _position.

As such, it doesn't care about context so your issue doesn't occur.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks :). It works. and it gives me new insight into JavaScript programming.

Comment: @Dolonro, you mean is a property has set/get methods, it becomes global? sorry i didn't get that right :(

Comment: @weima Nay, it becomes global because you've not correctly referenced the variable you were trying to edit. See my edit above

Answer (score 0):

This is setting a global variable `_position`:

```
setPosition: function (i) {
    _position = i
},
```

It is not the variable on your `pred` object.

When you access it here:

```
run: function () {
    return function (c_) {
        return make_cps(_position, c_);
    }(ret_) == 2;
}
```

you're using that global variable.

If you want to use instance properties, you're going to need to start using `this`:

```
setPosition: function (i) {
    this._position = i
},


run: function () {
    var pred = this;
    return function (c_) {
        return make_cps(pred._position, c_);
    }(ret_) == 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i get it. But i dont have any global property called `_position`. you mean property is created automatically?

Comment: Yes, you create it with `_position = i;`.